# Adding numbers using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

please help me this is my first time using Visual basic. This is the problem

Create a vb program. That will accept a number if the number inputted is equal to 1 display the sum of the 2 numbers, otherwise stop the program.

Comment: There's this fancy new thing called **Google**.  This question 100% has been answered before.  I can't even comprehend why you would ask here first...

Comment: I searched in google but i didn't find any answer. Please i need your help sir. How to do this. as my reference

Comment: You should actually learn the programming language before attempting to use it.  Literally all you have to do is watch like 2 tutorial videos and use your brain.  It's really not hard...

Comment: Or, you know, actually pay attention in the class that gave you this assignment.

Comment: `I searched in google but i didn't find any answer.` You really need to improve your googling skills!

Comment: :@foreverloveforme People on this site are willing and eager to help you, but you must understand that this site has a very specific purpose; to provide help with coding problems when you have written some code and are experiencing a specific, definable, problem.  You need to at least make a first attempt at writing some code.  I'm afraid nobody here is going to just do your homework for you.

Comment: Why not break the problem down into parts.  Start by writing a program that accepts two numbers as inputs, and does nothing else.  Then once you've done that, think about what to do with those numbers.  We've all been in the position of being frustrated students, but breaking a project into smaller sub-tasks is an essential software engineer's discipline and it's vital that you learn it.

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom This is a well known programming pattern, which goes under the name of `Divide et Impera` (Divide and Rule).

Comment: Well apart from the fact that this is some fairly simple logic and answered on the internet many times before, you still need to provide more information, is it a Windows Form Application or a Console Application or you know. Then it's just a case of declaring some variables and adding them together and adding an IF statement to check if the number is equal to one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This

    Dim inputno01 as integer

    Dim inputno02 as integer

    dim calculate as integer

If Integer.TryParse(txtinput.Text, calculate) Then
    if calculate=1 then

    dim total as integer
    total=inputno01+inputno02
    textboxtotal.text=total.string
    else
    me.close
```